# React Hooks: Update useState hook from a different .jsx file?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I have two components, each in their own file, that I would really like to keep separate, as the second one is reusable. However, I need to be able to update one of the hooks within the "child" component from the "parent" component. I have tried by passing in a value as a prop, but this won't actually set the value back to 0. I'm not even sure it does anything.

To be more specific, I am using a Material UI Tabs component in the child component, and would like to update the Tabpanel's "value" through the use of props from the parent component.

Here is an example [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-microservice-f8hju?file=/src/components/Food.jsx) that has the same issue.

To see the problem:

Type and select "vegetables" and then click on the second tab, "artichokes."
If you click on the search bar again and then select "fruits", the tab value will still be at "1" and thus the component will show nothing until you manually click on the "strawberries" tab.

You'll also get this error:

> MUI: The `value` provided to the Tabs component is invalid.
> None of the Tabs' children match with "1".
> You can provide one of the following values: 0.

Comment: the sandbox is not working... please provide a working example

Comment: For me sandbox was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions for your problem.

1. I would add `key` tag to your  component as below:

```
    <Food key={selectedFood} desiredFood={selectedFood} val={0} />
```

It will rerender your `Food` component with new props on `selectedFood` change.

2. More brutal - just use react hook - useEffect - i would not recommend it but you can add in your Food method this hook and set dependency array to `selectedFood`

   ```
     useEffect(() => {
        console.log("render");
        setValue(0);
      }, [props.desiredFood]);
   ```

It's just something quick that came into my mind and if i will think about better idea, i will share it.

Both solutions will rerender `Food` component on every `selectedFood` val change.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-hellman-hehlw?file=/src/components/FoodSearch.jsx:1731-1793) is my fork with working solutions i hope.

Comment: passing key won't work. Firstly it's the same property like desiredFood so it won't affect Food component rendering since desiredFood property in your example takes the same argument 'selectedFood'.

Comment: Second option will work, but it will be better to set Value with props.val(assuming it's initial value) to make code more resilient:
`
useEffect(() => {
     console.log("render");
     setValue(props.val);
   }, [props.desiredFood, props.val]);
`

Comment: Why passing a key won't work? It's not about being same as desiredFood, but unmounting component and 'reinitialize' it.